# Xcode 3.1.3 breaks console output

Tags: iphone, xcode, console

Today has been a headache - first my upgrade to xcode 3.1.3 trashed all my certs/provisions. After two attempts, I got them fixed.

Now, I'm dealing with the issue in the subject, no console output.
Absolutlely nothing is getting printed to the console - No startup info, not when I "print" a variable from xcode when stopped on a breakpoint,
not NSLog() either.

Nothing.

I've restarted my Mac, restarted Xcode, etc. I've made it so clears the console and opens it on project build. I had GDB log to a file,
and that works, so the plumbing is cool. Its just the console itself is dead.

Image: (and this is after attempting to print the contents of a variable while the app is running)
http://mr-sk.com/iphone/screen-capture-2.png

It doesn't seem to matter if I'm on the device or the simulator ...

Comment: File a bug report with apple - XCode 3.1.3 is considered pre-release software as of now and is under NDA

Comment: Do you see anything in the gdb output window rather than the console window?

Comment: Yes, I have TONS of data coming into the gdb.log file - almost too much to make much sense of it all.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the split bar is pinned all the way to the right side.  Look for the dimple and drag it back toward the right.

Comment: I wish. I read your comment and was ready to kick myself in the butt, but when I tried to fix it, it didn't work.

Damn - that' would have been a great save ...

Comment: Well, the view geometry is clearly screwed up. Try deleting your .perspective and .mode* files from your .xcodeproject/ wrapper.

Comment: Very cool - wasn't aware of those files/configurations. 

I fixed this by creating a new project and moving all my files into it. Kind of a pain, but it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also try asking in the iPhone developers portal forum, since you can ask about beta versions of stuff there...

Answer (score 0):

This is an older post, but I just recently ran into this with 3.2.3, so if someone happens upon this the answer by cdespinosa was spot on, however many of us "noobs" may not know exactly where to find those files, so just in case...

Go to Finder, find the folder where you have your .xcodeproject file and right click on it and click on show contents of this package.  When the new window appears, move the .perspective, .mode, .pbxuser files to trash.  (Make sure XCode is closed when you do this...I happened to do this while the project was open like an idiot and didn't think it worked the first time)

Now reopen xcode and your project.  Your console should now be fixed.